# ?Whether the setOnCheckedChangeListener tag is used to find IDs

Tags: android-studio, constants, expression, required

Hi I have encountered a small problem in Android Studio. I defined radiobutton IDs in XML, but when I called them in radiogrup, I encountered a constant expresiion required error for radiobuttons.Please help me my cod in MainActivitky is

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_main);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radioButton_main_1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " RadioButton is Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton_main_2:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " RadioButton is Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton_main_3:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " RadioButton is Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```